# ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Tags: c, gcc-warning

So I have this function, that is basically for `scanf` the name that a person will write and return it.

But, when I'm checking for errors, it says that I'm ignoring the value of `scanf`, when I'm actually returning it and using somewhere else.

```c
char* nomes (int n, char* nome ) {
    if (n == 1) printf(" Escolha o nome \n(max10 e sem espaços)\n");
    printf(" Jogador %d:",n);
    scanf("%10s",nome);
    print_linha ();
    return nome;
}
```

Comment: **return** value. That is, the value returned by `scanf` and not one of the args that it writes to. `int return_value = scanf(..);`

Comment: But i don't understand why I'm ignoring it.

Comment: Did you see my code and compare it with yours? Do you have a variable that is set from what `scanf` returns? You seem to be referring to `nom` which is not a return value.

Comment: But I don't need the value that scanf returns, if I set one like you did in  the first coment, I woudn't use it

Comment: That's what the compiler is telling you. You **should** use it. The fact you are not is the problem. The return value of `scanf` tells you how many inputs it was able to match. By ignoring it you are potentially ignoring failures and using invalid `nome` values (`scanf` will not put anything into `nome` if it fails).

Comment: Are you using any compiler option to enable warnings? Like `-Wall`? You might wanna suppress them. See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: @kaylum Oh, I get it now! Thanks

Comment: @kiner_shah yeah, I want to see the warnings

Comment: Is there a warning thrown or an error?

Comment: @kiner_shah That's not good advice. Suppressing valid warnings is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at `scanf` function for example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). It returns `int`. What you are doing in your code is you are using a parameter that was modified by `scanf`. Here is what you want:

```
char* nomes (int n,char* nome ){
    if (n==1) 
        printf(" Escolha o nome \n(max10 e sem espaços)\n");
    printf(" Jogador %d:",n);

    int result = scanf("%10s",none);
    // do something with result
    ...

    print_linha ();
    return nome;
}
```

If your don't need the return type you can simply cast it (but I think it is a bad practice):
`(void)scanf("%10s",none);`